# What presumption am I missing in the discrete mathematics problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

A collection of coins contains six different denominations: pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters, half-dollars, and dollars. How many coins must the
collection contain to guarantee that at least 100 of the coins are of the same
denomination?

To me, there can be infinitely many coins in the collection and there is still no guarantee that at least 100 of the coins are of the same denomination. What presumption am I missing here? This is the way the question appears in a chapter on the Pigeonhole principle.

Comment: You don't have to show that there are $100$ coins of *each* type—you have to show that there is *at least* one type of coins which there are $100$ of. I suppose your counterexample would be, say, a million nickels; that would still be correct, since there are still $100$ nickels.

Comment: Thank you. I just realized this myself right after solving the question that came after it. Now I feel stupid and not stupid at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

If there are infinitely many coins, then there are at least $100$ available of some type. If they're all allocated to a single denomination, for instance, that type has at least $100$ coins. If the infinity of them is distributed amongst multiple types, then the same is true. If I have infinitely many apples, then I do have $10$, and $100$, and $1,000$, and $10^{100}$ of them that I could give away to anyone.

Think of it like this to solve it: what is the worst-case scenario you can envision that still meets the constraints of not having $100$ or more coins of the same type? Obviously, just less than that, $99$ - for every type. From there, any additional coin allocated to any particular type will constitute $100$ and thus ensure at least one type has $100$.

Comment: Thank you. I just realized this myself right after solving the question that came after it. Now I feel stupid and not stupid at the same time.